# Generate Script for Event Notification

Tags: sql-server, event-notification, event

I need to migrate my Event Notifications from current server to another one. I would like to generate that code, but I couldn't find an way to do that.

**Try 1**

I have tried reverse engineering from `sys.server_event_notifications` but it does not return a value that I can marry with `sys.event_notification_event_typeid`.

**Try 2**

I tried also a DAC to query system views, getting more columns from that, but no joy.

**Try 3**

Tried `sp_helptext` the objects, but it can't be found.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT** (for one event)

```
CREATE EVENT NOTIFICATION [CaptureDeadlocks]
ON SERVER
WITH FAN_IN
FOR DEADLOCK_GRAPH
TO SERVICE N'DeadlockService', N'current database';
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of a way to script the existing one out so I drop and create a new one each time.
The following script assumes a database name of DBA and a Service of DeadlockEventsService (viewable in SSMS under Service Broker Services)

```
/****** BEGIN Create the Event Notification object that will capture the 

deadlocks ******/
USE [DBA]
GO

EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'sa';
DECLARE @AuditServiceBrokerGuid [uniqueidentifier]
,@SQL [varchar](max);

--— Retrieving the service broker guid of CaptureDeadlockGraph database

SELECT @AuditServiceBrokerGuid = [service_broker_guid]
FROM [master].[sys].[databases]
WHERE [name] = 'DBA'

--— Building and executing dynamic SQL to create event notification object

SET @SQL = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_event_notifications 
WHERE name = ''DeadlockGraphEventNotification'')

DROP EVENT NOTIFICATION DeadlockGraphEventNotification ON SERVER

CREATE EVENT NOTIFICATION DeadlockGraphEventNotification 
ON SERVER
WITH FAN_IN
FOR DEADLOCK_GRAPH
TO SERVICE ''DeadlockEventsService'', '''
+ CAST(@AuditServiceBrokerGuid AS [varchar](50)) + ''';'

EXEC (@SQL)

GO

/****** END Create the Event Notification object that will capture the deadlocks ******/
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the benefit of dropping one and recreating that. I need to generate the script to migrate that. Thanks for your response.